# Update shared preferences list data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, storage, preferences, shared

I just want to remove data from my List then set data up into shared preferences again, until now I added, listed and deleted my shared data but this time it doesn't work.

This is basically enough to update shared prefs. list

```dart
RaisedButton.icon(
  label: Text("Delete"),
  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
  onPressed: () async{
    SharedPreferences shared =  awaitSharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myList.removeAt(index);
    prefs.setString('myProducts', json.encode(myList));
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

I have this error:

[image]

Comment: Sorry guys,I just realized that i didn't use the shared variable as you can see, that was the problem. Normally i defined prefs variable under state but here i used both of them.

Comment: You should post that as an answer so that other people can use it if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're getting is a `NoSuchMethodError` pointing to setString. Checking the code shared, it looks like you're calling it on `prefs.setString('myProducts', json.encode(myList));` and it's likely that `prefs` hasn't been initialized. That's why the logs mentioned that the method was called on null. Make sure that you've initialized the SharedPreferences before calling the method.

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

await prefs.setString('myProducts', json.encode(myList));
```

Answer (score 0):

just update name of prefs From shared.

```
shared.setString('myProducts', json.encode(myList));
```

just call setString on Right Instance.